# D3: Zooming/Panning Line Graph in SVG is not working in Canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg

I created `zooming/panning` graph with d3 using `SVG`. I'm trying to create the same exact graph with `Canvas`. My issue is, when it comes to the zooming and panning of the `Canvas` graph, the graph is disappearing and I cannot figure out why. I created two JSBin's to show the code of both. Can someone assist me.

[**SVG - JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/xiqelab/1/edit?js,output)

[**Canvas - JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/xiqelab/edit?js,output)

My `SVG` zoom code looks like this:

```
// Zoom Components
zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, dayDiff*12])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed(){
    t = d3.event.transform;
    xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
    xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b'));
    focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis); //xAxis changes
    usageLinePath.attr('d',line); //line path reference, regenerate
}
```

My `Canvas` zoom code looks like this:

```
// Zoom Components
zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, dayDiff*12])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
    t = d3.event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
    context.save();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    draw();
    context.restore();
}

function draw() {
    xAxis();
    yAxis();

    context.beginPath();
    line(data);
    context.lineWidth = 1.5;
    context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
    context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Are you missing an x2 domain? x2.domain(x.domain());  If you can get the line and x and y axis to clear each time you zoom, it will work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one major source of grief that causes your line to disappear, and it is only triggered on the zoom:

```
function zoomed() {
    t = d3.event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());  // here
    ...
}
```

Rescaling won't work on `x2` as you haven't defined its domain. `x2` is your reference scale that is used to set `x` on each zoom, it should be the same as `x` to start with. However, the default domain for a `d3.timeScale()` is from January 1, 2000 to January 2, 2000 (see [API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleTime)), which won't work out for your data as your data does not overlap this period.

You need to set the domain of `x2` as well as `x`. If you do so after you set the initial domain for `x` with: `x2.domain(x.domain())`, you should get a chart that updates ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tovoxofara/edit?js,output)) as you now have a domain that overlaps your data.

However, now, the issue is that you need to clip your line, which you do in your svg example but not the canvas. To do so you could use something like:

```
function draw() {
    xAxis();
    yAxis();

  // save context without clip apth
  context.save();

  // create a clip path:
  context.beginPath()
  context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.clip();

  // draw line in clip path
  context.beginPath()
  line(data);

  context.lineWidth = 1.5;
  context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
  context.stroke();

  // restore context without clip path
  context.restore();
}
```

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qadowosima/1/edit?js,output)

And as we shouldn't let the axes overwrite themselves: Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gorisazuyi/edit?js,output) that erases the previous axes (with a commented out code block that redefines the y domain based on what values are contained in the selected x domain).

For good measure, here's a snippet of the last jsbin (scaled down for snippet view):

```js
var data = getData().map(function (d) {
        return d;
    });

    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = canvas.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = canvas.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    // setup scales
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, width]);
    var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    // setup domain
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return moment(d.Ind, 'YYYYMM'); }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.KSum; }));
    
    x2.domain(x.domain());
 


    // get day range
    var dayDiff = daydiff(x.domain()[0],x.domain()[1]);

    // line generator
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(moment(d.Ind, 'YYYYMM')); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.KSum); })
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        .context(context);

    // zoom
    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, dayDiff])
        .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
    
    d3.select("canvas").call(zoom)

    context.translate(margin.left, margin.top);

    draw();
//

    function draw() {
      // remove everything:
      context.clearRect(-margin.left, -margin.top, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      
      /*
      // Calculate the y axis domain across the selected x domain:
      newYDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
         if (  (x(moment(d.Ind, 'YYYYMM')) > 0) && (x(moment(d.Ind, 'YYYYMM')) < width) ) {
           return d.KSum;           
         }
      });
      // Don't update the y axis if there are no points to set a new domain, just keep the old domain.
      if ((newYDomain[0] !== undefined) && (newYDomain[0] != newYDomain[1])) {
        y.domain(newYDomain);        
      }
     //*/

      // draw axes:
      xAxis();
      yAxis();
      
      // save context without clip apth
      context.save();
      
      // create a clip path:
      context.beginPath()
      context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
      context.clip();

      // draw line in clip path
      context.beginPath()
      line(data);
      
      context.lineWidth = 1.5;
      context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
      context.stroke();
      
      // restore context without clip path
      context.restore();

 
    }

    function zoomed() {
        t = d3.event.transform;
        x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
       
      
        draw();
    }

    function xAxis() {
        var tickCount = 10,
            tickSize = 6,
            ticks = x.ticks(tickCount),
            tickFormat = x.tickFormat();

        context.beginPath();
        ticks.forEach(function (d) {
            context.moveTo(x(d), height);
            context.lineTo(x(d), height + tickSize);
        });
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();

        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.textBaseline = "top";
        ticks.forEach(function (d) {
            context.fillText(tickFormat(d), x(d), height + tickSize);
        });
    }

    function yAxis() {
        var tickCount = 10,
            tickSize = 6,
            tickPadding = 3,
            ticks = y.ticks(tickCount),
            tickFormat = y.tickFormat(tickCount);

        context.beginPath();
        ticks.forEach(function (d) {
            context.moveTo(0, y(d));
            context.lineTo(-6, y(d));
        });
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(-tickSize, 0);
        context.lineTo(0.5, 0);
        context.lineTo(0.5, height);
        context.lineTo(-tickSize, height);
        context.strokeStyle = "black";
        context.stroke();

        context.textAlign = "right";
        context.textBaseline = "middle";
        ticks.forEach(function (d) {
            context.fillText(tickFormat(d), -tickSize - tickPadding, y(d));
        });

        context.save();
        context.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
        context.textAlign = "right";
        context.textBaseline = "top";
        context.font = "bold 10px sans-serif";
        context.fillText("Price (US$)", -10, 10);
        context.restore();
    }

    function getDate(d) {
        return new Date(d.Ind);
    }

    function daydiff(first, second) {
        return Math.round((second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

    function getData() {
        return [
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201501,
                "TMin": 30.43,
                "TMax": 77.4,
                "KMin": 0.041,
                "KMax": 1.364,
                "KSum": 625.08
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201502,
                "TMin": 35.3,
                "TMax": 81.34,
                "KMin": 0.036,
                "KMax": 1.401,
                "KSum": 542.57
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201503,
                "TMin": 32.58,
                "TMax": 81.32,
                "KMin": 0.036,
                "KMax": 1.325,
                "KSum": 577.83
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201504,
                "TMin": 54.54,
                "TMax": 86.55,
                "KMin": 0.036,
                "KMax": 1.587,
                "KSum": 814.62
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201505,
                "TMin": 61.35,
                "TMax": 88.61,
                "KMin": 0.036,
                "KMax": 1.988,
                "KSum": 2429.56
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201506,
                "TMin": 69.5,
                "TMax": 92.42,
                "KMin": 0.037,
                "KMax": 1.995,
                "KSum": 2484.93
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201507,
                "TMin": 71.95,
                "TMax": 98.62,
                "KMin": 0.037,
                "KMax": 1.864,
                "KSum": 2062.05
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201508,
                "TMin": 76.13,
                "TMax": 99.59,
                "KMin": 0.045,
                "KMax": 1.977,
                "KSum": 900.05
            },
            {
                "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                "Ind": 201509,
                "TMin": 70,
                "TMax": 91.8,
                "KMin": 0.034,
                "KMax": 1.458,
                "KSum": 401.39
            }];
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: My apologies for the original 3rd js bin link, while it worked as intended, it wasn't the final code (it lost the commented out and optional y scaling and reversed the roles of scales `x` and `x2`). Luckily I copied that into the snippet when I answered, and have updated the jsbin accordingly.

Comment: I'm trying to add an area path along the same line, inside, but the area is covering the entire graph. Could you help me? [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lipejoneqo/edit?js,output)

Comment: You need to define the context for the area graph, and start a new path for each feature (this wasn't an issue for the line, but becomes one with the area). I've marked those changes as #1-#3 in this [bin](http://jsbin.com/jenonicoba/edit?js,output), I also removed styling on the clip area.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think you could possibly help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062295/canvas-graph-slow-performance-in-webview

Comment: I'll most likely have to offer another 500 points for this other issue that I linked, because i'm working on a mission critical app and i'm in dire need of help

Comment: I've taken a look, and am giving it some thought; however, I'm not very familiar with Ionic so I might not be the most useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the canvas each time you draw, by adding just inside the draw function,

```
context.clearRect(0-margin.left, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

and the rest is,

```
var data = getData().map(function (d) {
            return d;
        });

        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = canvas.width - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = canvas.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

        // setup scales
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, width]);
        var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        // setup domain
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return moment(d.Ind, 'YYYYMM'); }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.KSum; }));
        x2.domain(x.domain());

        // get day range
        var dayDiff = daydiff(x.domain()[0],x.domain()[1]);

        // line generator
        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(moment(d.Ind, 'YYYYMM')); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.KSum); })
            .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            .context(context);

        // zoom
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, dayDiff * 12])
            .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        d3.select("canvas").call(zoom)

        context.translate(margin.left, margin.top);

        draw();


        function draw() {
            context.clearRect(0-margin.left, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            xAxis();
            yAxis();

            context.beginPath();
            line(data);
            context.lineWidth = 1.5;
            context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
            context.stroke();
        }

        function zoomed() {
            console.log(d3.event);
            t = d3.event.transform;
            x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
            context.save();
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            // context.translate(d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[1]);
            // context.scale(d3.event.scale, d3.event.scale);
            draw();
            context.restore();
        }

        function xAxis() {
            var tickCount = 10,
                tickSize = 6,
                ticks = x.ticks(tickCount),
                tickFormat = x.tickFormat();

            context.beginPath();
            ticks.forEach(function (d) {
                context.moveTo(x(d), height);
                context.lineTo(x(d), height + tickSize);
            });
            context.strokeStyle = "black";
            context.stroke();

            context.textAlign = "center";
            context.textBaseline = "top";
            ticks.forEach(function (d) {
                context.fillText(tickFormat(d), x(d), height + tickSize);
            });
        }

        function yAxis() {
            var tickCount = 10,
                tickSize = 6,
                tickPadding = 3,
                ticks = y.ticks(tickCount),
                tickFormat = y.tickFormat(tickCount);

            context.beginPath();
            ticks.forEach(function (d) {
                context.moveTo(0, y(d));
                context.lineTo(-6, y(d));
            });
            context.strokeStyle = "black";
            context.stroke();

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(-tickSize, 0);
            context.lineTo(0.5, 0);
            context.lineTo(0.5, height);
            context.lineTo(-tickSize, height);
            context.strokeStyle = "black";
            context.stroke();

            context.textAlign = "right";
            context.textBaseline = "middle";
            ticks.forEach(function (d) {
                context.fillText(tickFormat(d), -tickSize - tickPadding, y(d));
            });

            context.save();
            context.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
            context.textAlign = "right";
            context.textBaseline = "top";
            context.font = "bold 10px sans-serif";
            context.fillText("Price (US$)", -10, 10);
            context.restore();
        }

        function getDate(d) {
            return new Date(d.Ind);
        }

        function daydiff(first, second) {
            return Math.round((second - first) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }

        function getData() {
            return [
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201501,
                    "TMin": 30.43,
                    "TMax": 77.4,
                    "KMin": 0.041,
                    "KMax": 1.364,
                    "KSum": 625.08
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201502,
                    "TMin": 35.3,
                    "TMax": 81.34,
                    "KMin": 0.036,
                    "KMax": 1.401,
                    "KSum": 542.57
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201503,
                    "TMin": 32.58,
                    "TMax": 81.32,
                    "KMin": 0.036,
                    "KMax": 1.325,
                    "KSum": 577.83
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201504,
                    "TMin": 54.54,
                    "TMax": 86.55,
                    "KMin": 0.036,
                    "KMax": 1.587,
                    "KSum": 814.62
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201505,
                    "TMin": 61.35,
                    "TMax": 88.61,
                    "KMin": 0.036,
                    "KMax": 1.988,
                    "KSum": 2429.56
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201506,
                    "TMin": 69.5,
                    "TMax": 92.42,
                    "KMin": 0.037,
                    "KMax": 1.995,
                    "KSum": 2484.93
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201507,
                    "TMin": 71.95,
                    "TMax": 98.62,
                    "KMin": 0.037,
                    "KMax": 1.864,
                    "KSum": 2062.05
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201508,
                    "TMin": 76.13,
                    "TMax": 99.59,
                    "KMin": 0.045,
                    "KMax": 1.977,
                    "KSum": 900.05
                },
                {
                    "BriteID": "BI-43dd32fe-ecbc-48d4-a8dc-e1f66110a542",
                    "Ind": 201509,
                    "TMin": 70,
                    "TMax": 91.8,
                    "KMin": 0.034,
                    "KMax": 1.458,
                    "KSum": 401.39
                }];
        }
```