# D3 Canvas graph zooming and panning slow redraw in Webview

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a d3 graph that I implemented in Canvas. The graphs performance is great in Chrome, but when I deploy it with Ionic(webview), zoom and pan redrawing are really staggering on android and even slower on iOS.

I originally developed the graph with SVG, but switched to canvas after being convinced that canvas would run smoother.

### **Setup Code**

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</ion-content>
```

**Canvas Initializing**

```
  mode = 'monthly';

  canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
      width = canvas.width - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = canvas.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

  // setup scales
  x = d3.scaleTime()
      .range([0, width]);
  x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  // setup domain
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return moment(d.usageTime); }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.kWh; }));

  x2.domain(x.domain());



  // get day range
  dayDiff = daydiff(x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]);

  // line generator
  line = d3.line()
      .x(function (d) { return x(moment(d.usageTime)); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d.kWh); })
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
      .context(context);

  area = d3.area()
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
      .x(function (d) { return x(moment(d.usageTime)); })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function (d) { return y(d.kWh); })
      .context(context);

  // zoom
  zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, dayDiff * 12])
      .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

  d3.select("canvas").call(zoom)

  context.translate(margin.left, margin.top);
  draw();
```

### **Draw Code**

The canvas draw code looks like this:

```
function draw() {

  // remove everything:
  context.clearRect(-margin.left, -margin.top, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw axes:
  xAxis();
  yAxis();

  // save the context without a clip path
  context.save();

  // create a clip path:
  context.beginPath()
  context.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.lineWidth = 0;
  context.strokeStyle = "none";
  context.stroke();
  context.clip();

  // draw line in clip path
  line(data);
  context.lineWidth = 1.5;
  context.strokeStyle = "steelblue";
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  area(data);
  context.fillStyle = 'steelblue';
  context.strokeStyle = 'steelblue';
  context.fill();


  // restore without a clip path
  context.restore();

}
```

### Zoom Code

My zoom code looks like this:

```
function zoomed() {
var t = d3.event.transform;
  x = t.rescaleX(x2);


  draw();

  var diff = daydiff(x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]);

  if (diff < 366 && diff > 120 && mode !== 'monthly') {
      mode = 'monthly';
      data = monthlyData;
      y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.kWh; }));
      return;
  }

  if (diff <= 120 && diff > 2 && mode !== 'daily') {
      mode = 'daily';
      data = dailyData;
      y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.kWh; }));
      return;
  }
}
```

The performance seems to increase when excluding the area path(not drawing it at all) from the canvas.

### The code

I'm attaching a link to the [`repository`](https://github.com/airasheed/canvas-d3-test.git). To make it run do the following:

1. git clone https://github.com/airasheed/canvas-d3-test.git
2. npm install
3. ionic serve <--for browser to see graph
4. ionic cordova build ios/android <--choose your testing platform
5. OR - ionic cordova emulate android/ios

I'd like to know if its a code performance issue or if the amount of data i'm using is what's causing the issue.

For the first zoom level there are **only 21 points**, to plot which is surprising. It seems its staggering when redrawing.

### **Benchmarking**

In chrome the `line(data)` method takes .5ms, but in the iOS webview it can take anywhere from 15ms - 40ms. It looks like its lagging and not responsive.

Comment: How large is the canvas? as what you have shown should easily be drawn quickly by almost all devices. If the canvas is too big that will cause a slow memory exchange between device RAM and Graphics hardware RAM to be able to render all the content. Ensure that the canvas is not larger than the device resolution. OR could be in the functions `line` `area` but not going to git just to comment, you should put all relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Blindman67 I've added the relevant code to the question. Thank you for commenting. The canvas is only `300px x 300px`.

Comment: @inspired try to run with installing `Crosswalk` and `WKWebview` for android and iOS platform and tel whether you facing the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the  `Crosswalk WebView Engine` Plugin Performance seems to be improved :

I have tested my Code with `Cordova Version : 6.5.0`

I have Tested this in Android Physical Devices (Nexus -6) . You can find the Full Code with the code in the [GithubRepo](https://github.com/Webrusterkk/Canvas-With-ionic)

Only case i need to verify  in the Android version  `4.4.4` above

Will update the benchmark status of the `iOS` after installing in the device.

**Update** :

Initially build was quite delay before installing the `WKwebview`. after installing the `WKwebview` from the [ionic-team](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) (Original Apache repo is quite buggy and ionic-team has modified this plugin to fit for them so it is better to add from here ) repo i can make it work with smooth transition

So Repo can be found  here :

https://github.com/Webrusterkk/Canvas-With-ionic

ionic-WKWebview Cordova Plugin :

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Comment: Transitions were smooth in iOs?

Comment: @inspired i have tried in iphone 6 plus , yes ,my benchmark was adding before & after that plugin. we even face this kind of behavior with other third party , after installing this plugin it solved our problem

Comment: Thank you but it says the ionic plugin is only used by iOS? what about android if i use it?

Comment: @inspired genreally code base will be single but `plugins` and `build's` need to be done seperately (Usually we build in VS , so i used to create two solutions in my local with same repo with different branches) at the time of building `Android` , i will use only android related plugin like `CrossWalk` and vice versa

Comment: @inspired we will not be check-in the plugins and platforms to repo so we never got any trouble

Comment: so my issue is not my code, its just the performance of the UIWebView?

Comment: @inspired , yes .. if you want i can send you the debug apk which i built using the Crosswalk plugin so that you install in your device , if its met your expectation then , its worth to try it out .. what do you say ? .. For iOS i'm afraid its long process to provide a debug build ...

Comment: I'm going to test it today. I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153941/discussion-between-webruster-and-inspired).